# How do I select multiple non-consecutive options from an html multiple select using just the keyboard in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

How do I select multiple non-consecutive options from an html multiple select using just the keyboard in chrome?

I am aware of methods in ie and firefox.

Here is an example multiple select: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit_view.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Comment: I *think* you'd use arrow keys to nav to the option you want, press and hold Ctrl, and then hit spacebar to select the option, but I don't have something to test on. Do you have a link to page I can test at?

Comment: Have added a test page... go nuts! Btw I believe you have described the Firefox way.

Comment: Side note to self: It is *not* Ctrl+Alt+Down, if you have an Intel graphics card.

Comment: Are you saying that holding the ctrl key down and then navigating with arrows and hitting space to toggle does not work?

Comment: Yes I am @horatio!

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in upcoming chrome update 80.0.3953.0 (after 8-ish years).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> - moves the focus independently from selection.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> - toggles selection of the currently focused item.

Thread: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=982450
Bug Fix: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/68562ee3f5eabfed9a480bfeb08d3d6bc7daa205

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no out-of-the-box solution for that. There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90172) with Google for that.

One way to do that is by using Javascript / Jquery (if your server supoorts it)  to select those fields.